# Literature on scientific achievements in physiological acoustics after Helmholtz

Tags: acoustics, biophysics, perception

I'm greatly interested in theoretical/mathematical/physiological aspects of music and the corresponding acoustics. As everyone knows, [the Greek](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musical_system_of_ancient_Greece) already discovered that consonant sounds seem to correspond to simple frequency ratios.

More recently, in the 19th century, Hermann von Helmholtz did distinguishable work in this area in his work [On the Sensations of Tone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensations_of_Tone). Surely there must have been new insights on this topic since then.

Can anyone provide information, i.e. and overview, on what has been achieved and point to corresponding literature?

**Update**
To be more precise, I'm not talking about the entire area of psycho acoustics, but specifically about topics related to harmony and consonance/dissonance.

Comment: Man, that's waaay too broad. **Yes, of course, there is a plenty of titles.** You need to be more specific and I dare to say that you didn't google *psychoacoustics* much.

Comment: @VictorPira Question updated.

Comment: That's not really a physics but a physiology questions which is partly modulated by culture.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is mainly about human physiology, not physics.

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I think this question will be closed, but I can provide a quick answer, since this is really close to my area of expertise.

Generally, we do not fully understand the sound perception. It is now well-known, that answer is not just in human physiology, but psychology and cognitive sciences as well.

The theory of simple ratios is in pythagorean meaning definitely incorrect. Ratios of equidistant tempered tuning are full of $\sqrt[12]{2}$ which is all but "pythagorean elegant" and despite that we percipe major triad in this tuning as consonant.

One of the popular models relates "rate of consonance" to the number of harmonics the sounds can get in common (of course, not with the same order - just the frequency equality) or "enough close" (way closer than a quarter tone). E.g. the sounds of fundamental frequency 200 Hz and 300 Hz have 600 Hz, 1200 Hz etc. in common (and that's a pure fifth).

You have asked for reference. Try the *Signals, Sound and Sensation* by William Hartmann.